# Why don't some summaries plotted in tensorboard?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorboard

I wrote k-means algorithm in tensorflow and tried to add minimal distance to summary:

[image]

Why don't plots have any length in horizontal dimension? What is on horizontal axis? What does `m` postfix mean?

The code is following:

```
        global_count = 0

        count = 0
        self.report.add_time_stamp(description="Initializing with k-means...")
        self.report.add_time_stamp(description="#\tdist")
        self.report.add_time_stamp(description="%d\t%.4e     " % (count, dist_min_sum_value))
        while dist_min_sum_value != dist_min_sum_value_old:
            count += 1
            global_count += 1
            dist_min_sum_value_old = dist_min_sum_value
            mu_value, cluster_indice_value, distance_square_value, dist_min_value, dist_min_sum_value = \
                sess.run([self.mu_assign_new_kmeans, self.cluster_indices_assign_new_kmeans, self.distance_square,
                          self.dist_min, self.dist_min_sum])

            if self.k_means_summary is not None:
                k_means_summary_value = sess.run(self.k_means_summary)
                self.k_means_writer.add_summary(k_means_summary_value, global_count - 1)

            print("%d\t%.4e     " % (count, dist_min_sum_value))
```

`k_means_summary` definition looks like

```
self.dist_min_sum_summary = tf.summary.scalar('dist_min_sum_summary', tf.squeeze(self.dist_min_sum))
...
self.k_means_summary = tf.summary.merge([self.dist_min_sum_summary])
```

Is it correct that I merge single summary?

Comment: the x axis is for the global_step argument of your summary, so global_count - 1 here. m means millions I think. It just looks like you're saving only 1 summary ever, maybe you could check that with some prints...

Comment: I am cheking this with prints and see many of them. Anyway, if I print one summary, why whould it scale to millions? How to rescale?

Comment: It's scaled automatically, it just does that kind of thing when there is only one point (same when there is only one value on the y axis). With multiple values it should autoscale to someting more reasonable, that shows all your values

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the script may only be writing 1 event. What is the output of running

```
tensorboard --inspect --logdir=[LOGDIR]
```

?

That should output counts for all event types. The format (but not the data) should look like this:

```
audio -
graph -
histograms -
images -
scalars
   first_step           0
   last_step            42
   max_step             42
   min_step             0
   num_steps            43
   outoforder_steps     []
sessionlog:checkpoint -
sessionlog:start -
sessionlog:stop -
tensor -
```